# Numerical methods for the continuity equation with Sobolev vector field

Tags: finite-element, pde, finite-difference, hyperbolic-pde, numerics

Consider the continuity equation 
$$
\partial_t \rho(x,t) + \operatorname{div} (b(x,t) \rho(x,t)) = 0, \qquad t \in [0,T], \quad x \in \mathbb R^N, 
$$
with $b \in L^1((0,T), W^{1,p}(\mathbb R^N))$.

- Have any numerical methods been used to approximate the (unique renormalized) distributional solution of this problem? Can you point out any references on this topic?
- What if we replace $W^{1,p}$ with $BV$?

Clearly, if $b$ is smooth, the problem is much more classical.

---

I've asked a related question on [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328576/numerics-for-continuity-equation-with-sobolev-vector-field) and a specific implementation problem (with a specific $b$ of bounded variation) on [Mathematica StackExchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/195547/numerical-methods-to-solve-a-continuity-equation).

Comment: I don't know much about numerical methods in this area, but for theory I would take a look at the books by Lions.